# Spark WRITE JDBC - Task Re-Attempt turnOff

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am working on process of reading from DB2 database using Spark and load into another Target - I have situation where, if any of the task fails due to any error, spark automatically re-attempts and rerun the task; this behavior is causing some data discrepancies while writing to target.

Can we turn off this behavior?

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `spark.task.maxFailures` to 1 to avoid task retries (default value is 4). 
From https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html :

```
Number of failures of any particular task before giving up on the job. The total number 
of failures spread across different tasks will not cause the job to fail; a particular 
task has to fail this number of attempts. Should be greater than or equal to 1. Number 
of allowed retries = this value - 1.
```